# javascript works only after developerwindow is opened

Tags: javascript

I'm having the problem that my js only runs when I have developer window opened en then load the page.

the code:

`function remove(id){
    alert("delete");
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete product with id " + id)){
        window.location = "index.php?page=products.php&remove=" + id;
    }
}`

`<a onclick='remove(1)' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>button</button>`

The strange thing is that another function does work normaly:

`function edit(id){
    window.location = "index.php?page=products.php&edit=" + id;
}`

`<a onclick='edit(1)' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>button</button>`

Can someone please help?
I have seen that there are same questions on here but these all have the answere that there is propebly a `console` or `console.log` somewhere, but I checked my whole project and it doesn't.

Comment: When the "dev console" is open, the browser loads o fresh version of the website instead of loading it from the cache. Probably, when it doesn't work, your browser is using an older version of your site.

Comment: How does it not work? What happens? Error message?

Comment: I found it. The problem was that I just remove as function name I renamed it and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It could've been caching the old version *or* you could've clicked "Do not show dialogs from this page", which would prevent the pop-ups.

With console open, you can right-click the "refresh" button in your browser and do a hard-reload which will remove the cache. This should fix the problem.